# Filter data in a big matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, out-of-memory

In MATLAB, I am dealing with a matrix URm of size [200K*150K] whose elements are between [0-5].

I would like to filter the values so I can have access the matrix enteries whose values are [4-5] and [1-2]. I am successful in the first case but I encounter error while trying to use the second one.

```
  Upos = sparse(URm > 3)       ;
  Uneg = sparse(URm<3 & URm>0) ;
```

I can obtain `Upos` but for `Uneg`, I encounter the following error:

```
Error using  < 
Requested 30711160620x1 (228.8GB) array exceeds maximum array size   preference. Creation
of arrays greater than this limit may take a long time and cause MATLAB to become
unresponsive. See array size limit or preference panel for more information.

Error in Provide_Information_about_URm (line 14)
Uneg = sparse(URm<3 & URm>0)
```

The error is more probably rooted on the fact that MATLAB generates an inner matrix before & operation is applied which takes huge space. How do you think the problem can be solved? Thanks for your opinions in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your expression `URm<3` is true for several values, including all zeros of `URm`, which is probably nearly every element. This results in a very large sparse matrix with only few nonzero elements.

Instead rewrite the logic in a way you never select the zeros

```
Uneg=xor(URm>=3,URm>0)
```

Comment: This is true, most of values in the matrix are <=3 and infact zero. To help, I am using sparse matrices. How can the problem be solved? I prefer to avoid loops!

Comment: @Yas: Updated my answer, took my some minutes to come up with a solution.

Comment: Daniel, brilliant idea! It works very well , thank you :-)